# AudioKit: Cannot create AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I use audiokit 4.9.1 and XCode 11.1. The code below works fine on:

iPhoneX (real device/simulator)

iPhone 11 (simulator)

**Not** working on 
iPhone 11 Pro/Max (simulator)

I get Export failed Error on `exportAsynchronously`:

> AKAudioFile+ProcessingAsynchronously.swift:exportAsynchronously(name:baseDir:exportFormat:fromSample:toSample:callback:):420:ERROR
>   export: cannot create AVAssetExportSession

I don't have a real iPhone 11 Pro so can't test if this is simulator problem or not. Any ideas?

```
   tape = aKit.recorder.audioFile!
   aKit.player.load(audioFile: tape)
   audioPlot?.resume()


   if let _ = aKit.player.audioFile?.duration {
      aKit.recorder.stop()
      tape.exportAsynchronously(name: "TempRecordedFile",
                                      baseDir: .temp,
                                      exportFormat: .m4a) {_, exportError in
                                        if let error = exportError {
                                            AKLog("Export Failed \(error)")
                                        } else {
                                            self.aKit.player.play()
                                            self.audioPlot?.node = self.aKit.player
                                            AKLog("Export succeeded")
                                        }
            }
        }
```

Also below AudioKit library source code, incase it helps, line 277:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Audio%20File/AKAudioFile%2BProcessingAsynchronously.swift

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for the AudioKit people? We can't debug third party code for you.

Comment: @matt thats why its tagged audiokit, which audioKit people here answer questions.

Comment: Fair enough, that sounds legitimate.

Comment: @matt although you are always welcome to make a wild guess, and I do the debugging to check if it helps :)